# Multithreading and array iteration (again?)

Tags: arrays, multithreading, iteration

I have a simple piece of code, and i would like to make it multithread friendly.

```
for(x=0;x<xLen;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<yLen;y++)
    {
        index = x*y+z;
        a[index] = a[index-1] + a[index+1] +a[index-lenX] + a[index+lenX];
    }
}
```

Normally i would divide xLen by thread count, and run every part in its own thread.
But dividing it in this case causes troubles and in some places results are based on wrong data ( for example index-1 holds value that has been already updated by it neighbours ).

Any body had this kind of problem before?
Is there any know approach for this kind of equation?

Comment: Currently, the entire calculation has a sequential dependency. There's no way to paralellize it without changing the results. Also, why are you using x*y+z as the index? I doubt that's what you intended.

Comment: Frankly, this code looks so sequence dependent that I'm not sure you CAN multi-thread it

Comment: Its an example of a problems that i am currently struggling with,  so i just wrote indexes and rest of code to show you general idea :).